# Error: "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials" when doing Docker build

Tags: python, docker, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to get the secret from AWS like so:

```
import boto3
import os

mysql_secret = os.environ['MYSQL_SECRET']

def get_secret():

    region_name = "us-west-2"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=mysql_secret)

    # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    return secret

secret = get_secret()
```

with Dockerfile

```
# Top level build args
ARG build_for=linux/arm64/v8
FROM --platform=$build_for python:3.11.4-bullseye as base

# Set docker basics
VOLUME /usr/app
ARG MYSQL_SECRET='mysql_secret'
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='some_key'
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'
ARG AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN='some_token'

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev  -y
RUN apt-get install pkg-config -y

RUN python -m pip install boto3

COPY ./test.py /usr/app/test.py
RUN python /usr/app/test.py
```

I looked around SO for a while and tried adding

```
ENV AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config
ENV AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

to the Dockerfile

I tried passing the credentials directly like

```
docker build . -t test:0.1 \
--build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${access_key_here} \
--build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${secret_key_here} \
--build-arg AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${us-west-2} \
--build-arg AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=${token_here}
```

Nothing seems to be working.

UPDATE:
I added

```
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='some_key'
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'
ARG AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN='some_token'
```

as recommended by Vasyl Herman and hard coded 3 out of 4 arguments, leaving out AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.
I then tried running
`docker build . -t test:0.1 --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${some_key}` but still getting the same error. Even though it works if access key is also hard coded in.

If i hard code the access key in, but leave out the secret key, i get a different error when running
`docker build . -t test:0.1 --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${some_key}`

:
`zsh: bad substitution`

Comment: What's the reason you are running that script at build time..?

Comment: @Paolo It's for an automated job that i will also need to set up terraform for afterwards. I just wanted to have it working before i upload it to aws so I can test it locally and make sure everything works.

Comment: The ARG directive in Dockerfile defines the parameter name and defines its default value. This default value can be overridden by the --build-arg <parameter name>=<value> in the build command docker build . The build parameters have the same effect as ENV , which is to set the environment variables. So, ARG in Dockerfile comes first. If no ARG then `--build-arg` will be ignored.

Comment: @VasylHerman that worked! But i was trying not to hardcode anything in tho :< I commented out the ARGS, copied all the values into the "docker build . -t test:0.1 --build-arg ..." string and tried running that and it didn't work again. Said "zsh: bad substitution". Why is that?

Comment: @Raksha, Just define the ARGs with no values. This is how ARGs work in Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ARG directives for AWS Keys like so:

```
# Example. Dockerfile with defined ARG directives

# Top level build args
ARG build_for=linux/arm64/v8
FROM --platform=$build_for python:3.11.4-bullseye as base

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
ARG AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN

# Set docker basics
VOLUME /usr/app
ARG MYSQL_SECRET='mysql_secret'

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev  -y
RUN apt-get install pkg-config -y

RUN python -m pip install boto3

COPY ./test.py /usr/app/test.py
RUN python /usr/app/test.py
```

Now you should be able to set or override values of predefined ARG directives running docker build command with `--build-arg` arguments.

Please, test. It has to be working.

**Super important note**: it's advisable to get secrets at run time, not at build time. Just keep in mind whatever your goal is here.

Comment: Thank you! I'm super new to Docker.
I tried running `docker build . -t test:0.1 --build-arg` with one argument at a time and it seems to be ok with all of them except AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY where it throws the "zsh: bad substitution" error.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the command you are running? Don't forget to mask any credentials.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your command looks OK. Try using the actual values first. Once it starts working improve it forther.

Comment: There might be a mistake in your `.env` file or `some_key` doesn't exist. Type `env` command in your terminal where you are running docker build to verify it.

Comment: but if you do `docker build . -t test:0.1 --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${some_key}` isn't it supposed to assigned that key there and then? It's not looking for it elsewhere, is it? So strange... And by `some_key`, i'm just putting in a string. Or is it supposed to be referencing some variable? I think that's what I'm doing wrong maybe, lemme try ...

Comment: Where you're running it? On an EC2 instance?

Comment: locally currently

Comment: yep, should've been a string, not `$()` .... *facepalm* ... So then where is whatever is in `$()`  supposed to be located? In the .env?

Comment: Run `export some_key=your-key-here` to create `some_key` env variable in your active terminal session.

Comment: If you're using docker compose you can leverage an `.env` file to enhance it further.

Comment: BTW, if you run on an EC2 instance boto library handles all API calls to the aws meta data endpoint to get the AWS Kyes. No need to set any ARGs we just played around with... Of course you have to have an instance profile configured properly

Comment: DO NOT do this. From the documentation: *It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like GitHub keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable values are visible to any user of the image with the docker history command.*